# How to create XLSX table without any style?

Tags: python, xlsx, xlsxwriter

Per [XLSX documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_tables.html#style), the default Table style output from Xlsxwriter is 
*TableStyleMedium9*. 
I don't want to style the table at all, how to do that?
I tried passing `{'style:' None}` and `{'style:' False}` to `add_table()` but those threw exceptions.

Reference: [Worksheet.py](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/blob/master/xlsxwriter/worksheet.py)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel itself, the default style is called "Normal" (within VBA as well).
Try passing that!

Comment: In case you're wondering how I got there (because in my localized GUI its called "Standard" instead). I simply recorded a Macro, applied the Standard-style to a piece of text and then looked in the VBA code what it said.

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't previously possible to do this. As of version 1.2.6 of XlsxWriter you can now set the style to `None`:

```py
worksheet.add_table('C3:F13', {'style': None})
```

Comment: How does this effect the filter? Can I only have the header filters?

Comment: It doesn’t affect the filter. That is still there.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the library and tried it myself. Simply put `{"style": ""}` in your options, and it should work just fine.

For example:

```py
worksheet.add_table('B3:F7', {"style": ""})
```

Comment: This works but slightly unintentionally. Nevertheless good workaround. Currently the "None" table style isn't supported in XlsxWriter. I've opened a feature request for it and will add it soon: https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/670

Comment: I tried "Normal" as suggested by @tst it seems to work.

Comment: Probably cleaner to use "Normal", I agree :)